# Post a CharField to an ArrayField in from React to Django using Axios

Tags: reactjs, arrays, django, axios

I am trying to create a feature where if a user writes a post the ID of the post goes into an ArrayField in the User model so a list of their writing can be accessed.

I introduced a new column in the User database, made the necessary migrations and trialed this feature just saving one post ID which worked fine. The issue arose when I made the model field an ArrayField. Now when I do the POST request I get an error

```
response
: 
"{\"posts_written\":{\"0\":[\"Expected a list of items but got type \\\"str\\\".\"]}
```

Currently I am writing the REQUEST as

```
    let newPost = new FormData()
    newPost.append('title', title)
    newPost.append('content', content)
      updatePostList.append('posts_written', id + ',')
      await API.patch(`/profile/user/${loggedInProfile.id}/update/`, updateArticleList, {
        headers: {
          'Authorization': `Token ${sessionToken}`,
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        },
      })
```

I am unsure of how to write the POST request to work with the ArrayField, I have looked online for answers but can't find anything.
I also tried wrapping the `id` in JS object brackets which did not work. I saw by using the Django Admin panel that manually adding to the `articles_written` field and separating values with a `,` saves them in a separate array index which is why I have appended a `,` to the `id`. I am out of ideas now though.

Here is the User model if that helps

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=36, default=generate_unique_id, primary_key=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True) 
    profile_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_images', default='/profile_images/DefaultAvatar.png')
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=500, default='', blank=True, null=True)
    display_name = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    articles_written = ArrayField(
        ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=36, blank=True, null=True)),
    )
```

Thank you

Comment: Please *don't* use an `ArrayField`, use `ManyToManyField`s...

Comment: I fail to see how `ManyToMany` would work here as there is only one `User` creating the post. One `User` can create many posts. I could have a `ForeignKey` field in the `Post` model to simulate a `OneToMany` relationship but then it doesn't seem elegant enough to iterate through all of the posts to see which `User` made which. There must be a better way. @WillemVanOnsem are you able to expand on your answer?

Answer (score 0):

After hours I finally found a solution so posting in case anyone comes across this in the future

I gave up trying to do this from the frontend and thought it would be more efficient if the `User` model can be updated from the backend.

I added a `ForeignKey` field to the Post model to simulate a One to Many relationship.

```
class Post(models.Model)::
    id = models.CharField(max_length=36, default=gen_uuid, primary_key=True)
    content = models.TextField(default='content')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Then in the User serializer i added the new field by querying the Post set.

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    post_set = PostSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        fields = (
            'id',
            'username',   
            'post_set'
        )
        model = User
```

Now the relationship is established
[image]